# Differences between Openstack and Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, openstack, cloudera

I can't clarify what are the differences between OpenStack and Cloudera.

As I understood, both are software you can install in your own cluster to manage it. But I guess that there are several differences between both, and... can they work together?

Can you give me further information about this? How could I use both?

Comment: Stackoverflow is  for programming questions, by the way. This belongs more to [su]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Openstack`** is an *open source cloud computing framework* which is deployed to have `virtualization` technology in your server and create identical cloud services that other cloud service providers are providing like `Amazon`, `Rackspace` and many more. 
`Instances` in `Openstack` are *virtual machines* which can be used for services as `Amazon` is providing to the world by giving computation services. We can even deploy `hadoop` provided by `Cloudera` in a virtual cluster created in `Openstack`.
Using `Openstack` is like owning a `Amazon` cloud but free of service.

**`Cloudera`** is *a US-based company which provides modified, improved and easily deployable apache hadoop*. The company is mainly focused on easing businesses to deploy hadoop according to the business needs. The company provides support for their product and provides trainings. 
lets say it like this
`Openstack` is a `framework` for *creating cluster* that supports  `Cloudera`'s hadoop to be deployed.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer, with your both answers now I can understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

**OpenStack** is an open platform for cloud computing (IaaS).The universe of applications running on an OpenStack backend is ever-expanding.

**Cloudera** provides Apache-Hadoop based software. It is used for big data.

Both can work together, you can deploy your cloudera cluster with [sahara plugin](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/cdh_plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks you so much, now I'm understanding it, I was confused and I was thinking both where the same kind of software/platform.